# Nature of Python Values, need a clarification

Tags: python

I just finished reading http://python.net/crew/mwh/hacks/objectthink.html and http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Just have a question now, are Python values always Objects (Are objects the only things that names can be bound to?) and moreover, are Objects the only game in PyTown...as the language doesn't have primitives, correct?

Comment: Yes, it's not like Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's objects all the way down, yes.

Integers, for example, have methods:

```
>>> 1 .__str__
<method-wrapper '__str__' of int object at 0x104ad7820>
```

and so do functions:

```
>>> def foo(): pass
... 
>>> foo.__str__
<method-wrapper '__str__' of function object at 0x104e62830>
```

Comment: Question: Since Python is implemented in C, is there no native way in Python to get say an `int8` from C?

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian: Look at the `ctypes` module, or use `struct` to interpret byte data that represents C-type data.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian Ctypes in CPython. However, this is unnecessary.

Comment: @Marcin Why is this unnecessary? Because numpy is a better solution?

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian: What are you trying to do that requires you to get an `int8` from C?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Nothing, just curious, but certainly there might be instances where I don't need the full range of integers provided by Python...wouldn't getting a int8 yield better use of memory?

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian Either there is no reason for you to worry about the size of an int, or if you need efficient mathematics, you can use numpy types. Basically the only time you need ctypes or its like is when you are interacting with C memory buffers for whatever reason.

Comment: Object overhead swamps any advantage of size-restricted integers unless you're using numpy. It's the same reason Python only has one floating-point type.